# Restricting scrollbars on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have two button - left and right  on my chart. I update my scroll position if the user clicks on the left or the right button.

```
  extremexmin = @chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min
  extremexmax = @chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max
  differenceMinMax = extremexmax - extremexmin
  extremexmax = extremexmin
  extremexmin = extremexmax - differenceMinMax
  #console.log "date is - " + extremexmin + " <<>> " + extremexmax
  @chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremexmin, extremexmax)
```

The problem I am facing is that when the user reaches the end of the chart I want to disable the left or the right button respectively. But then how do I identify if the scrollbar has reached the end of the chart.

If the scroll bar has reached its end and if I continue clicking the right or left button then it shows empty space on the chart.

Let me know how do I identify the max and min value for scrollbars and accordingly disable the buttons.

I tried using datamax and datamin but with every click the values for datamax and datamin are updated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Before setting new extremes in `@chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes()` you have also access to `dataMin` and `dataMax`. So now, just check if your new calculated extremes aren't outside the range of data min/max. If aren't -> set new extremes, if are outside -> button should be disabled.

You can also disable button after setting new extremes.